# How to recursively find a set of a characters in a string?

Tags: javascript, string, algorithm, search, recursion

I need to write a function where given a set of characters `key` find the number of unique instances occuring in a string `str` such that

```
findKeys("fooo","foo") //returns 3
//foo-
//fo-o
//f-oo

findKeys("foobarfoo","obo") //returns 4]
//--ob----o 
//-o-b---o-
//-o-b----o
//--ob---o-
```

The following is the function I have so far, I don't know what I'm missing but I just know that it's not finding all the instances, so it's not iterating through the string correctly.

```
function findKeys(str, key) {
  var count = count || 0;

  if(str.length <= key.length || key.length === 1) {

    if(str.slice(0, key.length) === key) {
      return 1
    }

    return 0
  }

  if(str[0] === key[0]) {
    count += findKeys(str.slice(1), key.slice(1))
  }

  count += findKeys(str.slice(1), key)

  return count
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just remove

```
|| key.length === 1
```

from your function. I'm not sure why you have that in there - that ends up giving the wrong result when key.length is 1 but str.length is > key.length (since you are not considering the cases where you skip some characters in str and match the later characters of string with key).

Comment: Woah. That was a quick response, and you're absolutely right. It was right in front of me and I was clueless. Can I ask how you saw that so quickly? I've been looking at this for days and have tried writing out every function call to try to better visualize what's happening.

Comment: I just read the rest of it - that made sense. Key.length seemed fine on the first pass (an oversight I made), but when I came back to it I wondered why you needed it since the first part should have taken care of it. A little more time on that got me to why it would cause it to fail. Then, I ran a couple of testcases to make sure it worked, and posted.